# Run Exchange server and Linux webserver on "one" IP address

Tags: linux, networking, apache-2.2, web-server, exchange

I currently have an Exchange server on my network but am looking to step away from the whole Microsoft ecosystem. I would like to setup a Linux webserver on my network and host all my sites on there and bypass the exchange server and its IIS. Is this possible to do without using port numbers in the address? Is it possible to run an Apache webserver in front of my exchange box?

Also, the exchange server is still running and I need to be able to reach it as well. I have not found a suitable solution that would allow me the same benefits as Exchange 2010. Once I do, the Exchange box will be phased out.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This might be better on ServerFault

Comment: Why do you need them on a single IP address?  These are different services and it makes sense to host them on separate machines on separate IPs.  You should just need to update your DNS records to point to the correct IPs.

Comment: They need to be on the same IP address because I do not want to pay another 10 to 15 a month for another IP address. They will run on separate machines but the same Public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first:

Yes, it is possible to host multiple-websites on Apache on single IP address without mentioning the port number within the URL. It can be done using Name-Based Virtual Hosting feature of Apache and you may follow some examples here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Mind you: Do NOT use IP-Based Virtual Hosting in above step and it will help you setting up Exchange on same IP later.

Once, all your websites are ported from IIS to Apache and hosted using Name-Based Virtual Hosting (and automatically listening at default port 80, thus not required to mention the port number within browser while accessing), You may setup the Exchange on same or different machine within your local-network and access it using its name (not IP) from remote locations. You can achieve that using NATing within your local network (Refer following URLs):

http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html
http://computer.howstuffworks.com/nat2.htm